# base Link is invisible in Gazebo-11

Tags: urdf, ros-humble, gazebo-11, spawn-model, ros2-launch

I dont understand why the base_link is transparent, every other Link looks fine.

```
<link name="panda_link0">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://panda_description/meshes/visual/link0.dae" />
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://panda_description/meshes/collision/link0.stl" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
     <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <mass value="3.06" />
        <inertia ixx="0.3" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.3" iyz="0.0" izz="0.3" />
      </inertial>
    </link>
    <link name="panda_link1">
        <visual>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://panda_description/meshes/visual/link1.dae" />
            </geometry>
        </visual>
        <collision>
            <geometry>
                <mesh filename="package://panda_description/meshes/collision/link1.stl" />
            </geometry>
        </collision>
          <inertial>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <mass value="2.34" />
        <inertia ixx="0.3" ixy="0.0" ixz="0.0" iyy="0.3" iyz="0.0" izz="0.3" />
      </inertial>
    </link>
 
    <joint name="panda_joint1" type="revolute">
        <safety_controller k_position="100.0" k_velocity="40.0" soft_lower_limit="-2.8973" soft_upper_limit="2.8973" />
        <origin rpy="0 0 0" xyz="0 0 0.333" />
        <parent link="panda_link0" />
        <child link="panda_link1" />
        <axis xyz="0 0 1" />
        <limit effort="87" lower="-2.9671" upper="2.9671" velocity="2.3925" />
    </joint>
```

```
<gazebo reference="panda_link0">
        <material>Gazebo/green</material>
    </gazebo>
     <gazebo reference="panda_link1">
        <material>Gazebo/Green</material>
```

```
    <link name="world"/>
    
<joint name="base_joint" type="fixed">
    <parent link="world"/>
    <child link="panda_link0" />
    <origin xyz="0.0 0.0 0.0" rpy="0.0 0.0 0"/>
</joint>
```

[image]

Comment: but i can see all the links in Rviz

Comment: @jsotola I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally solved the Problem. The Color tag is Gazebo/Green and not Gazebo/green.